# Is Ada.Containers.Functional_Maps usable in Ada2012?

Tags: ada, gnat

The information about [`Ada.Containers.Functional_Maps`](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/the_gnat_library.html#ada-containers-functional-maps-a-cofuma-ads) in the GNAT documentation is quite—let's say—abstruse.

First, it says this:

> …these containers can still be used safely.

In the second paragraph, it seems to me that you cannot free the memory allocated for those objects once the program exits the context where they are created. I am understanding that you could run into a memory leak. Am I right?

> They are also memory consuming, as the allocated memory is not reclaimed when the container is no longer referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Read the next two sentences in the doc:

> Thus, they should in general be used in ghost code and annotations, so that they can be removed from the final executable. The specification of this unit is compatible with SPARK 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Because the specification of [`Ada.Containers.Functional_Maps`](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/the_gnat_library.html#ada-containers-functional-maps-a-cofuma-ads) is compatible with SPARK, it may help to examine it in the context of related [*SPARK Libraries*](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/spark2014/html/spark2014_ug/en/source/spark_libraries.html) with regard to proof, testing and annotation. In particular,

- The functional maps, sets and vectors are unbounded collections of indefinite elements that are neither controlled nor limited. While they are inefficient with regard to memory, they are simple, immutable and useful "to model user defined data structures."
- The functional containers can be used in [*Ghost Code*](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/spark2014/html/spark2014_ug/en/source/specification_features.html#ghost-code), "parts of the code that are only meant for specification and verification", as suggested [here](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/spark2014/html/spark2014_ug/en/source/spark_libraries.html#functional-containers-library). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877792/230513) illustrates a ghost function.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems to me that you cannot free the memory allocated for those
> objects once the program exits the context where they are created. I
> am understanding that you could run into a memory leak. Am I right?

There are some things that you can do in Ada to [manage memory](https://archive.fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/ada_memory/), I would be surprised if (for example) the usage of an instance inside a declare-block were not cleaned-up on the block's exit. — This is, in fact, how some surprisingly robust applications can get away without "dynamically-allocated" memory/values (it's actually heap-allocated, but that's pedantic).

This sort of granular control is really nice, as you can constrain things/usages to specific points. Combined with Ada's good facilities for presenting interfaces, this means that changing some structure to another can be less-painful than it otherwise might be.

As an example of the above, I had a nested key-value map (a JSON object) that was being used to pass parameters around; the method for doing this changed and so I had a string of values (with common-rooted keys) coming in and a procedure that took JSON as input. Obviously what was needed was a "keys&values-to-JSON function, so inside the function I used the multiway-tree container where the leafs represented values and the internal-nodes the keys, the second step was to traverse the tree and create the JSON-object as needed - simple recursion and data-structure selection used to address the problem of adapting the textual key-value pairs of these nested parameters to JSON. — And because the usage of multi-way trees was exclusive to this function, I can be confident that the memory used by the intermediate tree-object I used is released on the function's exit.