# Does Ada deallocate memory automatically under some circumstances?

Tags: memory-management, ada

I was trying to find some information as to why the keyword `new` can be used to dynamically allocate objects but there is no keyword like `delete` that could be used to deallocate them. Going through mentions of `Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation` in *Ada 2012 Reference Manual* I found a few interesting excerpts:

> Every object is finalized before being destroyed (for example, by
> leaving a subprogram_body containing an object_declaration, or by a call to an instance of
> Unchecked_Deallocation)

> Each access-to-object type has an associated storage pool. The storage allocated by an allocator comes
> from the pool; instances of Unchecked_Deallocation return storage to the pool.

> The Deallocate procedure of a user-defined storage pool object P may be called by the implementation to
> deallocate storage for a type T whose pool is P only at the places when an Allocate call is allowed for P,
> during the execution of an instance of Unchecked_Deallocation for T, or as part of the finalization of the
> collection of T.

If I had to guess, what that means is that it is possible for an implementation to automatically deallocate an object associated with an *access* when the execution leaves the scope in which *access* was declared. No need for explicit calls to `Unchecked_Deallocation`.

This seems to be supported by [a section in *Ada 95 Quality and Style Guide*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/95style/html/sec_7/7-6-6.html) which states:

> The unchecked storage deallocation mechanism is one method for overriding the default time at which allocated storage is reclaimed. The earliest default time is when an object is no longer accessible, for example, when control leaves the scope where an access type was declared (the exact point after this time is implementation-dependent). Any unchecked deallocation of storage performed prior to this may result in an erroneous Ada program if an attempt is made to access the object.

But the wording is rather unclear. If I were to run this code, what exactly would happen on the memory side of things?

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   procedure Run is
      X : access Integer := new Integer'(64);
   begin
      Put (Integer'Image (X.all));
   end Run;
begin
   for I in 1 .. 16 loop
      Run;
   end loop;
end Main;
```

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   procedure Outer is
      type Integer_Access is not null access Integer;
      procedure Run is
         Y : Integer_Access := new Integer'(64);
      begin
         Put (Integer'Image (Y.all));
      end Run;
   begin
      for I in 1 .. 16 loop
         Run;
      end loop;
   end Outer;
begin
   Outer;
end Main;
```

Is there a guaranteed memory leak or is `X` deallocated when `Run` finishes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As outlined in [*Memory Management with Ada 2012*](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/%7Edirk.craeynest/ada-belgium/events/16/160130-fosdem/09-ada-memory.pdf), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66972081/230513), a local variable is typically allocated on a *stack*; its memory is automatically released when the variable's scope exits. In contrast, a dynamic a variable is typically allocated on a *heap*; its memory is allocated using `new`, and its memory must be reclaimed, usually:

- Explicitly, e.g. using an instance of `Unchecked_Deallocation`.
- Implicitly, e.g. using a controlled type derived from `Finalization`; as noted [here](https://www.adaic.com/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-7.html#4), when the scope of a controlled instance exits, automatic finalization calls `Finalize`, which reclaims storage in a manner suitable to the type's design.

The children of `Ada.Containers` use controlled types internally to encapsulate access values and manage memory automatically. For reference, compare your compiler's implementation of a particular container to the corresponding functional container cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787269/230513).

Ada offers a variety of ways to manage memory, summarized on slide [28](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/%7Edirk.craeynest/ada-belgium/events/16/160130-fosdem/09-ada-memory.pdf) in the author's order of preferability:

1. Stack-based.
2. Container-based.
3. Finalization-based.
4. Subpool-based.
5. Manual allocate/deallocate.

In the particular case of `Main`, the program allocates storage for 16 instances of `Integer`. As noted on slide [12](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/%7Edirk.craeynest/ada-belgium/events/16/160130-fosdem/09-ada-memory.pdf), "A compiler *may* reclaim allocated memory when the corresponding access type goes out of scope." For example, a recent version of the GNAT reference manual indicates that the following storage management implementation advice is followed:

> A storage pool for an anonymous access type should be created at the point of an allocator for the type, and be reclaimed when the designated object becomes inaccessible.

Absent such an indication, the storage is not *required* to be reclaimed. It *is* typically reclaimed by the host operating system when the program exits.

Comment: The author himself [explains](https://archive.fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/ada_memory/) slide 12 and claims that memory may be reclaimed when an access type goes out of scope. According to [ARM](http://ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-11.html) (18/4) it is actually required for access types which specify Storage_Size. I don't think the claim that the program will leak 16 Integers is entirely correct.

Comment: @GDI512: Yes; an implementation is _permitted_ — but not _required_ — to reclaim the memory in your example; I've tried to clarify above.

Comment: Right, I think I understand now. But what about named access types? I couldn't find any strong guarantees in ARM so I assume the same rules apply but maybe I haven't read into it enough. Are there any strong guarantees from the standard or GNAT when the access type goes out of scope? (Added another example to illustrate what I mean)

Comment: @trashgod: I feel it is a bit misleading to say that Finalization implements implicit deallocation. Finalization implements an implicit call of the Finalize procedure when an object of a controlled type is "destroyed", which typically happens when the scope of a stack-allocated controlled object is left. But if some heap-allocated memory should be deallocated at that time, the Finalize procedure must explicitly deallocate it, typically by using Unchecked_Deallocation.

Comment: @NiklasHolsti: Agreed; I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @GDI512: Ada [controlled types](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-7-6.html) have "a `Finalize` procedure which is invoked immediately before finalization of any of the components of a controlled object." More above.

Answer (score 4):

Do your programs leak memory? It depends on the compiler.

AFAIK, there are only two times when a compiler is *required* to reclaim allocated memory:

1. when an access type with `Storage_Size` specified goes out of scope
2. when an instance of `Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation` is called with a non-null value

However, a compiler is *allowed* to reclaim memory in other cases. For example, a compiler may implement garbage collection, but I don't know of any that do.

FWIW, I don't know of any compiler for which your programs don't leak memory.