# What happens in Ada when memory is deallocated?

Tags: memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, ada

I'm totally new to Ada, and I have to learn it for a course I'm having in school.

One of the exercises I've done asks for a procedure to swap pointers' adresses, then to change a pointer's address to another, and to free that previous address.

As you can see in the next example, I'm doing what is required, but I was curious to see what happened to that address when it's freed up, by holding a reference to it, and realizing it puts garbage in it, I'm guessing the flags from that address changed, and something tells the compiler than that memory address has been liberated, I'm just not sure nor can find something online that says that my assumption is correct or not.

```
procedure Main is
   type T_Pointer is access Integer;
   I, J, aux: T_Pointer;
   
   procedure FreeMemoryAddress is new Unchecked_Deallocation(integer, T_Pointer);
   
   procedure ChangePointerAddress(Origen: in out T_Pointer; destino: in T_Pointer);
   
   procedure ChangePointerAddress(Origen: in out T_Pointer; destino: in T_Pointer)
   is
   begin
      origen:=destino;
   end ChangePointerAddress;

   procedure SwapPointers (I, J: in out T_Pointer);

   procedure SwapPointers (I, J: in out T_Pointer)
   is
      aux: T_Pointer;
   begin
      aux := new Integer;
      Aux := I;
      I:=J;
      J:=Aux;

   end SwapPointers;


begin

   I:=new Integer;
   J:=new Integer;

   Put_Line("i's uninitialized value: " & integer'Image(I.all));


   Put_Line("i's address: " & System.Address_Image(I.all'Address));
   Put_Line("j's address: " & System.Address_Image(j.all'Address));


   SwapPointers(I, J);
   Put_Line("After swapping:");
   Put_Line("i's address: " & System.Address_Image(I.all'Address));
   Put_Line("j's address: " & System.Address_Image(j.all'Address));
   
   aux:=j;
   FreeMemoryAddress(j);
   Put_Line("aux's value: " & Integer'Image(aux.all)); --garbage
   Put_Line("aux's address: " & System.Address_Image(aux.all'Address));

end Main;
```

Comment: A side note: with `aux := new Integer;` in `SwapPointers` you produce a memory leak. Just remove that line...

Comment: Another side note : if there is specific behaviour you want, you can just declare a controlled type, and implement that behaviour in its initialize, adjust and finalize procedures, knowing that finalize will be called when it is deallocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was a little surprised to see that the initial value of `I.all` was 0, since the compiler isn’t required to make sure that allocated memory is initialized (at least, [ARM 2012 4.8(9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-8.html#p9) says "any implicit initial value is assigned", see [ARM 3.3.1(10)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-3-1.html#p10), none of which are the case here). GNAT for VxWorks 5.3 used not to initialize allocated data, which resulted in surprises for people who’d developed on Windows when they moved to the VxWorks target; we made our own version of the memory allocator (`s-memory.adb`), which filled memory with `16#deadbeef#`.

Our allocator also filled deallocated memory with a similar but different pattern (`16#feebdaed#`? - it was a while ago).

On macOS, and probably in this case, the GNAT memory deallocator calls the C `free()`, which will do whatever it does. The returned memory may be overwritten as part of re-linking it into the system memory arena, and/or reused immediately, for example by your post-`Free` code.

Answer (score 4):

Some aspects of memory management in Ada are outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67131931/230513). In the particular case of [`Unchecked_Deallocation`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-11-2.html), the standard advises that an instance "should actually reclaim the storage." As @Simon Wright [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72301614/230513), the deallocation details may be implementation specific—marking, zeroing or poisoning freed memory—depending on the host operating system. MacOS, for [example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425778/does-macos-automatically-erase-freed-memory-to-prevent-leakage-of-information-l), uses several such security-related strategies; you may want to research your OS.

In the variation below, I've added a `Default_Value` aspect and code to display the value of `J` before and after being freed. Try referencing the value of `J.all` after the call to see the error raised by attempting to dereference `null`.

```
Before Free (J):
J value: -1
J address: 000060000085C030
After Free (J):
J value:  756334640
J address: 000060000085C030
```

Code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation; use Ada;
with System.Address_Image;       use System;

procedure Main is
   type Int is new Integer with Default_Value => -1;
   type Int_Ptr is access Int;
   I, J, Temp : Int_Ptr;

   procedure Free is new Unchecked_Deallocation (Int, Int_Ptr);

   procedure SwapPointers (I, J : in out Int_Ptr) is
      Aux : Int_Ptr := new Int;
   begin
      Aux := I;
      I   := J;
      J   := Aux;
   end SwapPointers;

begin
   I := new Int;
   J := new Int;
   Put_Line ("I & J values: " & Int'Image (I.all) & " " & Int'Image (J.all));
   Put_Line ("I address: " & Address_Image (I.all'Address));
   Put_Line ("J address: " & Address_Image (J.all'Address));
   SwapPointers (I, J);
   Put_Line ("After swapping:");
   Put_Line ("I address: " & Address_Image (I.all'Address));
   Put_Line ("J address: " & Address_Image (J.all'Address));

   Put_Line ("Before Free (J):");
   Put_Line ("J value: " & Int'Image (J.all));
   Put_Line ("J address: " & Address_Image (J.all'Address));
   Temp := J;
   Free (J);
   Put_Line ("After Free (J):");
   Put_Line ("J value: " & Int'Image (Temp.all)); --garbage
   Put_Line ("J address: " & Address_Image (Temp.all'Address));
end Main;
```