# How do you handle resourece release while handling an exception in ADA?

Tags: exception, resources, ada

Does ADA have an equivalent of C++'s destructors or Java's try-with-resources? That is, a technique where I can say that a resource acquired in this function is released when this function exits: whether normally or due to the handling of an exception. Is there a way to express such concept in ADA?

Comment: See also [*Does Ada deallocate memory automatically under some circumstances?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67131931/230513).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled` ([ARM 7.6, Assignment and Finalization](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-7-6.html)).
(why `limited`? because you really don’t want to copy the object you’ve created so as to release the resource).

This is a very very simple demo of the concept; release the resource at the point where I output `** finalizing a Protector **`.

```ada
with Ada.Finalization;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Raii is

   type Protector is new Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled
     with null record;
   overriding procedure Finalize (Obj : in out Protector);

   procedure Finalize (Obj : in out Protector)
   is
   begin
      Put_Line ("** finalizing a Protector **");
   end Finalize;

begin

   Put_Line ("declaring a simple scope");
   declare
      P : Protector;
   begin
      Put_Line ("quitting the scope");
   end;

   Put_Line ("declaring a scope to be quit via an exception");
   begin
      declare
         P : Protector;
      begin
         Put_Line ("raising CE");
         raise Constraint_Error;
      end;
   exception
      when Constraint_Error =>
         Put_Line ("CE caught");
   end;

   Put_Line ("done.");

end Raii;
```

The output is

```
$ ./raii
declaring a simple scope
quitting the scope
** finalizing a Protector **
declaring a scope to be quit via an exception
raising CE
** finalizing a Protector **
CE caught
done.
```